# how to convert image to sprite code like this for mario fullscreen

Tags: javascript, json, sprite, fullscreen

i downloaded this game mario fullscreen
https://codeload.github.com/karol-f/FullScreenMario/zip/refs/heads/master
and i want to change characters and the of characters is like this, how i can convert an image to this, there is a parser.html in this code but it doesn't works.

this code is in library.js

```
p[0,6,8,10]x05,x25,x07,11x27,1100111131311313x16,3313113133x15,33311113331100x35,113333x05,331333313x06,33x16,3x05,222211112220003332233332233003333223322333003333212212333003333x26,333000333x26,3300
```

[image]

the game is this :

[image]

the parser is this . it don't give me sprite code

[image]

Comment: You might be better asking this over on GitHub, where someone in the know may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the information about this sprite format here:
https://github.com/FullScreenShenanigans/EightBittr/tree/main/packages/pixelrendr